# IntelliJ IDEA default Monospaced font is not same as on the product page

Tags: java, angular, windows, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have just tried to install IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (Trial) and Community Edition and use Darcula theme in addition to default settings in my PC with Windows 10 operating system. However, I have not observed the font and theme seen on the [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) page as shown below:

[image]

Although my default settings already set font as Monospaced used in IntelliJ IDEA, the result is completely different as shown below. So, how can I fix this? If this is related to Linux or Unix, can I use this settings in my Windows machine?

[image]

Comment: On my MacBook, the default font is "sf ns text"; it looks like the screenshots were taken from MacOS

Comment: Different default fonts are used on different OS. So you could manually select the most suitable font.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I installed as es explained steps on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71470/how-to-use-san-francisco-font-on-windows. But I am not sure if it is the same as the given page on IntelliJ Idea. On the other hand, I think there is not a Windows version and I had to convert it finally. Thanks...

Comment: @y.bedrov So, which font would you suggest for Windows that is most similar to IntelliJ Idea?